How to automate ffmpeg to split and merge parts of video, and keep the audio in sync?
I have a Python script that automates trimming a large video (2 hours) into smaller segments and then concatenating them without re-encoding, to keep the process fast. The script runs these ffmpeg commands:
import subprocess

# Extract chunks
segments = [(0, 300), (300, 600), (600, 900)]  # example segments in seconds
for i, (start, length) in enumerate(segments):
    subprocess.run([
        "ffmpeg", "-i", "input.mp4", "-ss", str(start), "-t", str(length),
        "-c", "copy", "-reset_timestamps", "1", "-y", f"chunk_{i}.mp4"
    ], check=True)

# Create concat list
with open("list.txt", "w") as f:
    for i in range(len(segments)):
        f.write(f"file 'chunk_{i}.mp4'\n")

# Concatenate
subprocess.run([
    "ffmpeg", "-f", "concat", "-safe", "0",
    "-i", "list.txt", "-c", "copy", "-y", "merged_output.mp4"
], check=True)

All chunks come from the same source video, with identical codecs, resolution, and bitrate. Despite this, the final merged_output.mp4 sometimes has audio out of sync—especially after the first chunk.
I’ve tried using -ss before -i to cut on keyframes, but the issue persists.
Question: How can I ensure correct A/V sync in the final concatenated video when programmatically segmenting and merging via ffmpeg without fully re-encoding? Is there a way to adjust the ffmpeg commands or process to avoid audio desynchronization?

For -ss, I am not sure, but I would say that, with copy codec, it doesn't really matter if you but it after or before. For me the problem is with usage of concat, that drops timings embedded in segments, and just suppose that all streams (audio and video) have the exact same length. Which is not necessarily the case, and usually, this is not a problem, because timings tell when to play them.

But, anyway, that is not easy. I had a set of video handling scripts with ffmpeg (to generate quick montage from extracts, using just radio button in a very simply GUI, without the need for a video edition software), and to solve this, I ended using a very very grotesque method: I used pairs of raw YUV and .wav as format for sequences (so, with each 1920×1080×2 bytes corresponding to exactly 40 ms, that is exactly 7680 bytes of the 16bits stereo 48kHz wav.

But then, here goes the speed: that forces reencoding obviously. Plus, I had to buy a dedicated hard drive. So not at all an advice to do so. Just to say: when I had the same problem, I gave up, and used that grotesque method (which, for the huge encoding/storage price it costs, is very very specific to a fixed format, bitrate, framerate, etc. But that is also your case)

Yeah, I'll try to find some more ideas around this. Thanks for the input anyhow

Have you looked into segment muxer?

I tried it, but don't remember exact steps any more. I just found a way that works, and it is split+merge with mkvmerge and then just -c with ffmpeg to mp4

Solution is to use mkvmerge, and then copy back to mp4
import subprocess
import os


# Function to convert seconds to HH:MM:SS format
def convert_to_hms(seconds):
    hours = seconds // 3600
    minutes = (seconds % 3600) // 60
    secs = seconds % 60
    return f"{hours:02}:{minutes:02}:{secs:02}"


# Segments defined as (start, end) in seconds
segments = [(0, 300), (300, 600), (600, 900)]  # Example segments in seconds
input_file = "input.mp4"
base_name = os.path.splitext(input_file)[0]

# Directory for temporary chunks
temp_dir = "./temp_chunks"
os.makedirs(temp_dir, exist_ok=True)

# Normalize time and prepare mkvmerge parts
split_parts = []
for start, end in segments:
    start_hms = convert_to_hms(start)
    end_hms = convert_to_hms(end)
    split_parts.append(f"{start_hms}-{end_hms}")

split_parts_str = ",".join(split_parts)
split_file = os.path.join(temp_dir, f"{base_name}_split.mkv")

# Split the input file into chunks using mkvmerge
print(f"Running mkvmerge to split into parts: {split_parts_str}")
subprocess.run([
    "mkvmerge", "-o", split_file, "--split", f"parts:{split_parts_str}", input_file
], check=True)

# Check if the split parts exist
part_files = sorted([
    os.path.join(temp_dir, f)
    for f in os.listdir(temp_dir)
    if f.startswith(f"{base_name}_split-") and f.endswith(".mkv")
])

if not part_files:
    print("No split parts found. Exiting.")
    exit(1)

# Merge the parts using mkvmerge
merged_file = f"{base_name}_merged.mkv"
merge_cmd = ["mkvmerge", "-o", merged_file]
merge_cmd.extend(part_files)

print(f"Merging files: {part_files}")
subprocess.run(merge_cmd, check=True)

# Convert the merged MKV file to MP4 using ffmpeg
output_file = f"{base_name}_processed.mp4"
print(f"Converting merged file to MP4: {output_file}")
subprocess.run([
    "ffmpeg", "-i", merged_file, "-c", "copy", "-y", output_file
], check=True)

# Cleanup temporary files
for f in part_files:
    os.remove(f)
os.rmdir(temp_dir)

print(f"Processed video saved to {output_file}")

